# Duplicating tasks and subtasks SharePoint 2013

Tags: tasks

I have an instance of SharePoint 2013 that my company is testing to see if it fits our requirements for a task management point of view and there are 2 things that don't seem to be obvious.

1. Is it possible to duplicate a task and all subtasks
   I have tried copy paste but that doesn't work.
   I have tried dragging a task but this only copies the task and not all subtasks
2. Threaded notes on tasks
   I see there is the possibility to apply new columns to tasks but we need to make it easy for resources to add notes to tasks while they are working on them.

If these 2 points are possible and intuitive we will deploy otherwise our other option is ASANA.

Thoughts?